# PrimeNG p-table methods keeps firing on table click

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a p-table with a set of 12 items (which are not lazy loaded).
Some of this data has methods computing different things in HTML. The problem is that all these methods keep being called on every table click, not matter where I click. Those methods are NOT binded to the click event - they are just returning some data as string etc.

Is there any way to disable that propagation, so my methods are not called on every table click? I just want to render this table once and don't change anything.
I don't need to use onLazyLoad, because the data is small enough that I can load it in OnInit.

p-table looks somewhat like that

```
  <p-table [value]="data"
       dataKey="id"
       [rowHover]="true"
       [filterDelay]="0"> 
          <div>{{ calculateCurrentTime() }}</div>
  </p-table>
```

And calculateCurrentTime() is firing every time I click on the table (no matter when). I tried setting lazy="true" won't help, but without success.

It's important to note that inside this table I have a button which I want to be able to click.

Comment: hi @itharius can you post snippets of codes

Comment: Hi @BikaleG, added snippets, ty for suggestion

Comment: What is the use of calculateCurrentTime()? When you need to call this function..?

Comment: This method is put in html template in order to return time string. But aside from that, this method is getting called EVERY time I click on the table (no matter when). So for me it looks like p-table is being re-rendered every time it's clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below issue is occurred due to calling the function from the template, we should not call a function in the template.

> this method is getting called EVERY time I click on the table (no
> matter when)

An alternative way to call the function is in ngOnInit() and assign it in a variable. It will get the current time during initiating the table component.
Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getTabledata();
}

public getTabledata() {
 this.data = response.data;
 this.data.forEach(item => {
   // Update only below particualar object in the data.
   if (item.id = 13) {
    item.currentTime = this.calculateCurrentTime(item);
   }
 });

}
```

In Template:

```
  <p-table [value]="data"
       dataKey="id"
       [rowHover]="true"
       [filterDelay]="0"> 
         // You can get this item by looping the data. I am just adding the condition
          <div>{{ item.currentTime ? item.currentTime : '' }}</div>
  </p-table>
```

Ref Link for `Why You Should Never Use Methods Inside Templates in Angular`:

https://betterprogramming.pub/why-you-should-never-use-methods-inside-templates-in-angular-497e0e11f948

Thanks

Comment: Sounds great, but what if I want to use this method only on SPECIFIC entry in array. Say only when data.propertyX = Y then I want to return remaining time. So from 15 entries I would need to use it with only one, but how am I to get that dynamically rendered property and use it like like showRemainingTimeCounter(element13Data)

Comment: From my understanding, you need to call this function only when an record element matches your condition. I am right..?

Comment: Yeah, that's true and it's always one element in the whole array, so I want to pass it's data dynamically in html (e.g calculateCurrentTime(element13Data)) istead of having to filter it in ts file.

Comment: I think it is worth it to use pure pipe https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations

Comment: Updated the answer kindly check my answer.

Comment: Thank you @JaiSaravanan, it helped me with the issue. Therefore I mark this thread as solved.

Comment: @Itharius, kindly upvote if it helped you.